# Android minSdkVersion uses always minimum sdk even higher api devices

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, minimum

I use minimum sdk version 1.6 and run app on android device 4.0 but the app layout look likes devices with android 1.6. Is not it possible to use proper sdk based on device android version?

For clear my mean, suppose:
I use min sdk version 1.6 and target 8.0. I want when it runs on device version 4 it uses sdk 4, on device version 5 it uses sdk 5 and so on.

Comment: I am not sure about xamarin, but there is something called **appcompat library** which makes your app run on lower API versions with a look of higher API version.

Answer (score 1):

You can support different API levels creating multiple APKs taking advantage of this Google Play feature.

It’s essential to adopt some good practices from the get-go and prevent unnecessary headaches further into the development process.

[Creating Multiple APKs for Different API Levels](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html) explains these steps in detail.